# Angular Reactive Form Set Value Not working

Tags: angular

I have an Angular Reactive form (Angular version 9).

The form requires a select dropdown which is populated by an `enum`.

I import the enum, and filter over the keys in the constructor to pull out the string text to create the dropdown.

```
myForm: FormGroup;
statusList = StatusEnum;
statuskeys: any[];

constructor(
    private alertify: AlertifyService,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private service: MyService,
  ) {
    this.statuskeys = Object.keys(this.statusList).filter(String);
  }
```

so the status list would look something like this:

```
[
  "Ignore",
  "Post",
  "Return",
]
```

Now, because I'm *editing data* I need to get the status of the object being edited from the db and set that value as the default value for the reactive form. So the goal of the below code is to: 1) create the form and the validation rules, 2, call the setStatus function which should take the array of possible statuses and check to see if the property 'status' on the object to be edited exists, if so, get the index of it from the status list and set the default value of the dropdown to that index instead of index[0].

I try to do this with this code:

```
createEditForm() {
    this.setStatusOnFormControl();
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [this.objectToBeEdited.title, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      description: [this.objectToBeEdited.description],
      status: [this.statuskeys[0]],
    });
  }

setStatusOnFormControl() {
    var indexOfStatus = this.statuskeys.findIndex(x => x === this.objectToBeEdited.status);
    if (indexOfStatus != -1) {
      this.myForm.setValue({
        status: this.statuskeys[indexOfStatus]
      })
    } else {
      this.myForm.setValue({
        status: this.statuskeys[0]
      })
    }
  }
```

Running this code gets me two console log errors (without this code, the form works fine). I do pass a form group into the html by calling `createEditForm` in `ngOnInit`:

```
Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
core.js:6241 ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

I have console logged `indexOfStatus` and is not equal to undefined before the `setValue` function gets called...

Answer (score 0):

The `setValue` method should work as expected as soon as it is has a `FormGroup` instance.

In your code, you call the method `this.setStatusOnFormControl();` before you initialize the variable `myForm` and this throws an exception. This results to get the errors in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure formGroup is initialised and To set all FormGroup values use, setValue:

```
this.myForm.setValue({
  title: 'yourTitle', 
  description : 'desc',
  status: 'yourStatus'
});
```

To set one or more values, use patchValue:

```
this.myForm.patchValue({
  status: this.statuskeys[0]
});
```